# ArrayFormula Google Sheets - remove high and low from average

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to use an `arrayformula` to calculate the average across 7 columns while removing the max and min number from those columns. The tricky part is there is no preset limit on how may cell will be filled, each time its different.

I have the formula to calculate the average complete:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$A),"",IF($J$2:$J="Granted",($AO$2:$AO+$AP$2:$AP+$AQ$2:$AQ+$AR$2:$AR+$AS$2:$AS+AT2:AT)/6,0)))`

I've tried using the `Trimmean` function but it isn't working with the array formula, `=Trimmean(AO2:AU2,0.33)` any suggestions on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values in the cells that you want to ignore are empty, you want :

```
Average of all cells that are filled and not maximum or minimum
```

Which is

```
Sum of all cells that are filled and not maximum or minimum / (number of filled cells - 2)
```

Thus

```
=(sum(YourRange)-max(YourRange)-min(YourRange))/(count(YourRange)-2)
```

should give you what you want

Comment: That formula does fill down using an array formula